# SQL Server pivot datetime records

Tags: sql-server, datetime, pivot

When I execute the following statement:

```
select *
from data
where startdate >= '4/06/2018' and enddate <= '11/06/2018'
```

I get these results:

[image]

I would like to get this result in SQL Server:

[image: pivot]

Is this possible in SQL Server? I'm not sure if I need to use a pivot or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes this is possible. It would require using a tally table as the main table in your query with a left join to data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a calendar table or tally table, you can use an ad-hoc tally table in concert with a `LEFT JOIN`

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2018-06-04'
Declare @Date2 date = '2018-06-11'

Select A.[Date]
      ,Val = sum(isnull(B.Val,0))
 From (
        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) [Date]=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) A
 Left Join YourTable B 
  on  A.[Date] >= B.StartDate and A.[Date] < B.EndDate
 Group By A.[Date]
 Order by A.[Date]
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Val
2018-06-04  0
2018-06-05  2
2018-06-06  2
2018-06-07  3
2018-06-08  3
2018-06-09  0
2018-06-10  0
2018-06-11  0
```